# Why won't my varidic arguments work in C?

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to create my own printf function, but it's not working. The output seems to be the correct format but the parameters aren't getting passed correctly it seems, and I get garbage values. I am using GCC. See the code below.

```
void con_printf(char *fmt, char attr, ...)
{
    char *s = printf_buffer;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(s, CON_TMPSIZE, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    while(*s != '\0')
    {
        con_putchr(*s, attr);
        s++;
    }
    con_flush();
}
```

printf_buffer is defined as CON_TMPSIZE bytes long, which is 128 bytes in this version. This is for a small microcontroller, but I expect the principle applies to any processor.

I am calling it like this:

```
con_printf("LOOP a %d\n", 0, 10);
con_printf("LOOP b %d\n", 0, 12);
```

I expect LOOP a 10 to be printed on the first line, and LOOP b 12 on the next, but I get LOOP a 542 and LOOP b 542.

Comment: Kindly show us the caller, and the arguments being passed in.

Comment: @EvilTeach - added caller code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `va_start` you specify, at which point the variable arguments start.

Since your function's variable argument list starts after `attr`, you'll need to:

```
va_start(args, attr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it is still not working. The output has not changed from what it used to be.

Comment: Hmm. I fired up my virtual machine, ran that code and it gave me the expected results. What machine is your code compiling on?

Comment: It is running on a microcontroller, a dsPIC33FJ128GP802.

Comment: Well Thomas, could you try and switch the functions arguments (i.e. attr first, then fmt) and try again. If there's no change, I'm as lost as you...